# How to add "customer total order count" to opencart 3 Invoices

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am using opencart 3.0.3.2. With the module in the link below, I can see the "customer's total order quantity" on the order page. but I want to see **"customer's total order quantity"** on the **invoice page**. How can I do this? can you help me?

[image]

That is, when we print out the invoice to prepare the order, I want to be able to see if the customer has placed an order before.